# How do I change the date format of the auto-generated ticker on x-axis

Tags: ticker, dygraphs

I like how dygraph generates the ticker on x and y axis,

I do not want to write a new ticker function as i am fine with the way dygraph generates them and adjust them based on the view window, just want to localize the date format and add some of my own text

just to be more clear,

I like the way dygraph  shows only the time (HH:MM) if all the tickers are within the same day, 
and if they cross over to another day, they show in HH:MM format but they at crossover point they show the DD-Mon format

I want to keel all these feature but like to format as per the locale.

is there an easy way out where I can specify this?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [axisLabelFormatter](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#axisLabelFormatter) option.

Comment: Hi danvk, first of all thanks for providing us this awesome library. I did look into axisLableFormatter, but if I specify a format for xAxis will it not apply the same format to all the lables? Insted I want the dygraph way if the label display HH:MM then i want to change the time format and if the lable is DD-Mon then I want to change the date format. Is it possible to know if the format of the default label and then apply mine in axisLabelFormatter option?